# class require into a method

Tags: php

i have a class, with a method can be return an instance of other, ex:

```
class a {

    public function foo() {

    }

    public function bar() {
          return new b();
    }

}
```

The class "b" is in another file, i can do:

```
require_once('b.php');

class a {

    public function foo() {

    }

    public function bar() {
          return new b();
    }

}
```

But i include a class and this not usage in mayor of cases. I actualy do:

```
class a {

    public function foo() {

    }

    public function bar() {
          require_once('b.php');
          return new b();
    }

}
```

Realy a don't use the require function, i use a import function thath use require, but i do it (and not autoload) for the class names (we use packages and don't use namespaces).

This works, with out error, warining, notices, etc. Is wrong do it?

Comment: No problem, is correct use. But i recomended use spl_autoload_register and require here the classes.

Answer (score 2):

This is fine. Make sure you don't have any statements that are not part of a class/function as they would only be executed/available in the `bar()` function

Answer (score 2):

I think it's more a matter of personal choice. Because PHP is interpreted, unlike C per example, the compiler does not need to know class definitions before runtime, so you can use `include` directives anywhere in your code.

Both will have an advantage and a disadvantage: if you always include at the beginning of your script, you can easily figure out what dependencies your class have, but you may load classes that will not be used at runtime. Obviously, doing the opposite will have the exact inverse effect.

Either is acceptable.